# How do I cover the attic rafter bays after installing baffles from the soffit before replacing the siding?

Tags: insulation, exterior, soffit

Should I be covering exposed fiberglass batts I stuffed into rafter bays below stapled in plastic baffles with an air barrier, such as with foil faced rigid foam board or house wrap, before replacing soffits and reinstalling siding?

Comment: Stories don't make good questions on SE. Most people that might be able to help won't read past your 3rd sentence. I'd recommend reorganizing this to get directly to the question.

Comment: thanks for the feedback, just don't want to go over stuff I've already done or spend time answering loads of questions and not getting to a specific answer, want to get siding back up before it rains Fri.

Comment: I merged the other question with this, feel free to edit it further. One other suggestion is to include a photo since some people may have a difficult time visualizing where the insulation is exposed.

Answer (score 1):

I have never seen anything done to cover the insulation. I have install repaired replaced many soffits.